# How to configure email client in Dynamics 365 to send a email through workflow process?

Tags: dynamics-crm, email, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365

I am new to Dynamics 365 and I am creating a workflow to send an email but email is not sent as I am getting error in email sent.

This is configuration issue So how to configure email in Dynamics 365 to send an email.

Answer (score 1):

Server side sync is the answer you are looking for.

[Technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn832099.aspx) says the 2nd option is deprecated.

```
•   Server-side synchronization
•   Microsoft Dynamics 365 for Outlook (includes a synchronization agent).
```

Setup a service account & it’s mailbox record should be configured for outgoing (in your case) as SSS, also to be tested & enabled apart from O365 Admin approval of this mailbox.

[Read more](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt622056.aspx)